# Clearing "sessions" collections in mongoDB mean stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, mean-stack

I am using Mean Stack (mean.io) app on heroku, and just noticed that my "sessions" collection is getting pretty big, and I couldn't find any job in mean that clears it.

[image]

is there a preferred way of clearing it using Mean stack?

Update:
Immediately after posting question I found this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Might do the trick actually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Heroku, but on OpenShift it's easy to add a RockMongo cartridge, which gives a great interface to your MongoDB database. I see that it's available on Heroku too: http://www.paasmag.com/2011/11/30/how-to-manage-mongodb-on-openshift-with-rockmongo/